# Reuse static variable in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

I am trying to reuse a static hash inside a setup method in a hadoop job.

```
    private static Map<Long,String> amostraTable = null; //class variable

    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

    if (amostraTable == null){
                amostraTable = new HashMap<Long,String>();
                System.out.println("Hashmap allocated!");
            } else{
                System.out.println("Hashmap reused");
                return ;
            }
}
```

I set `mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks=-1`
I just want to reuse the hashmap. but every mapper are logging: Hashmap allocated!

Is there any other parameter to set?
The mappers task are consuming to many CPU to allocate/populate the hashmap.

**EDIT:**
Look at this post: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/201206.mbox/%3COFC497A21A.62B05EC6-ON85257A14.006F8FF6-85257A14.006FE8C7@freddiemac.com%3E

"If i understood correctly, 
then if I initialize a static variable (say var) in setup() and when 
mapper is started for the 2nd time on same JVM, the that var would be 
already initialized before setup() is called i.e it is retaining its value 
from previously run mapper.
Is this the way ?"

**EDIT**
mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks: JVM reuse no longer supported
mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks: JVM reuse no longer supported

**EDIT**
Hadoop 2.x does not support JVM Reuse. So my first option is to use: MultiThreadedMapper. I will make my HashMap thread safe. Is this a good option?

Comment: Your code is not thread safe. Imagine that you have:
1. T1: if (amostraTable == null) evaluated to true
2. T2: if (amostraTable == null) evaluated to true
3. T1: a new instance is created
4. T2: another instance is created

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have multiple threads not seeing the variable update. Why don't you just declare it inline and make it final? Also a [CHM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) might be more appropriate:

```
private static final Map<Long,String> amostraTable = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```